# DNS problem and inbound rules for dockerized Jenkins on AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, jenkins, dns, amazon-ecs

I'm setting up a dockerized Jenkins server on AWS using ECS.

Here is what I have now.

1. A dockerized Jenskins Master running on a EC2 instance.
2. A ECS cluster for dockerized Linux agents.
3. A ECS cluster for dockerized Windosw agents.
4. Both Linux and Windows agents can connect to master by jnlp using Jenkins ECS plugin.

Questions:

1. How can I set a security group for Master ec2 instance to allow the IP of all ECS cluster instances, now I manually set the IPs of Linux and Windows instances of ECS cluster to the inbound rules so containers can connect to master on port 8080, but those IPs change.
2. The container agent for code building launched from ECS cluster can not parse the company's DNS (Server host name and SVN link of my company are reported as unknown), what is the right way to resolve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Cant you reach to master ec2 via its private ip address? ECS cluster instances and the EC2 instance will have a private ip addresses.

Comment: I set the private IP as Jenkins URL, the agent failed to connect to master. Now Jenkins URL has to be a public IP, which is a elastic IP I associated to the master ec2 instance.

Comment: You can use NATGATEWAY to make the IP static

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the private ip addresses instead of going via public internet. The EC2 instance's security group can allow a private ip subnet such 10.1.0/24. The ECS instances can connect to the EC2's private ip address for e.g 10.2.1.1.

Comment: Sorry i missed the part about SVN. where is the SVN server hosted. in AWS or on-prem

Comment: Thanks. SVN server is hosted on-prem.